# How to test my action on google home device

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created an action in my account and tested in simulator, it is coming properly, but i am not able to test the same in google home device.
I have downloaded the google home app and paired it with google home device. it got connected successfully, but unable to test the same in google home device.
Can you please help in this regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- Make sure the google home is connected on the same google account as the one you use to create the google action
- (Don't think this is necessary) Is the device on the same wifi?